# How to test a “.xap” file on a Windows Phone 8 device?

Tags: windows-phone-8

Please tell me how I can testing a .xap file on a Windows Phone 8 device? Can I install XAP file on WP 8 without SDK8?

Answer (score 0):

By testing on WP8, I think you mean deploying your app to a physical device. For this you need two things:

- dev-unlock your phone. You can do this if you have signed up for an MSDN dev account, or know someone who has
- Deploy your application to your device by plugging your phone in to your PC, PIN-unlocking it, and setting the target to Device in

Comment: SDK8  necessary that deploy app on wp8?